# facebook fb:follow callback method

Tags: facebook, events

We have an application where we added fb:follow to allow visitors to follow our application on the facebook. We want to make some changes to the system based on user checking fb:follow callback. We searched the web for fb:follow button but with absolute no luck. Can someone help us getting solution for this. We need callback method for fb:follow.

Comment: Did you try the same event subscription? Something tells me it should work.. `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create'...`